# Kendo UI checkbox value checked using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I want to get the values of the checkboxes if true then i need to add the calculated values in the Total column my code is

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid<SSTS.Models.ServiceUsedViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          // columns.Bound(student => student.CustomerName);
      //    columns.Bound(student => student.StudentNumber).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
         // columns.Bound(student => student.GivenName).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.ForeignKey(p => p.StudentNumber, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["students"], "StudentNumber", "StudentNumber")
        .Title("StudentNumber").Width(150);
          columns.Bound(student => student.FirstDateOfTravel).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.MondayAM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.MondayPM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.TuesdayAM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.TuesdayPM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.WednesdayAM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.WednesdayPM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.ThursdayAM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.ThursdayPM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.FridayAM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.FridayPM).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.TotalNumberOfDaysAM).Width(150).ClientTemplate("#= calculate() #"); ; ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.TotalNumberOfDaysPM).Width(150);//.ClientTemplate("#=MondaydPM#"); ; ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);
          columns.Bound(student => student.IsMoreThanOneService).Width(150); ;//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);



            columns.Command(commands =>
          {
              commands.Edit(); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items
              commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items
          }).Title("Commands").Width(150);
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()) // The "create" command adds new data items
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) // Use inline editing mode
      .DataSource(dataSource =>
          dataSource.Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(student => student.ServiceUseID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                model.Field(p => p.StudentNumber).DefaultValue("");       

            })
                            .Create(create => create.Action("serviceUse_Create", "ServiceUse")) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
                                            .Read(read => read.Action("serviceUse_Read", "ServiceUse"))  // Action invoked when the grid needs data
                                    .Update(update => update.Action("serviceUse_Update", "ServiceUse"))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
                                                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("serviceUse_Destroy", "ServiceUse")) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item
      )
          .Pageable().Scrollable()
```

%>

I have MondayAM/PM-FridayAm/PM checkboxes and there is TotalNumberofDaysAM/PM and i need to check how many AM/PM are checked and then add them to the totalnumber column anyone knows how to do it using jquery or javascript

Answer (score 1):

You might try using jQuery `:checked` selector:

```
// Get reference to Grid
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
// Get the list of `input` that are checked
var clicked = $(":checked", grid.element);
// Display the length of the array that contains the inputs that are checked
console.log("clicked", clicked);
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JB2TD/

Comment: thanks for the reply but scenario is different i have a column TotalnumberofAm and totalnumberofPM and the count of mondayAM/PM-FridayAM/PM needs to be filled in those columns

Comment: Do you mean that what is different is where and when to show the counter or what to count?

Comment: i have monday Am-tuesday Am-wedAM thursday AM FridayAM and same as PM checkboxes and two columns for TotalNumebrofAM and PM and when any of the Am or PM checkbox is checked then count need to be add in the Total column

Comment: If you would have only one counter I would suggest some jQuery for counting when changing the checkbox value but having two and being only seven elements it is likely that the easiest way is actually checking the values in the model.

Comment: Despite of that, you might try marking AM HTML elements with some CSS class (using a template) and the same for PM. Then on data change find the row in the grid for that item, find checkboxes `checked` that are marked with AM or PM and updating the counters. But as you can see it is going to be a lot of code (also slow since they need to traverse the DOM) for counting something that you can easily do.

Comment: i am new in programming can you show me some code or example of how to do it